# Safety of concurrent_vector

Tags: c++, concurrency, ppl

it is known that operator [] is not concurrently safe for writing:
[concurrent_vector::operator[] Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355262.aspx)
But what if I guarantee that different threads will write to different vector positions.
Like this (very much simplified example):

```
concurrent_vector<double> vec;
vec.resize(100);

parallel_for(0, 100, [&] (double ind)
{
    vec[ind] = ind*ind;
}
```

Is it concurrently safe or not? And if 'not' then why?
Thanks

Comment: _That_ would be safe even with regular old `std::vector<>`. What problem are you experiencing to prompt this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is concurrently safe as it's like if you are accessing different variables.

As ildjam pointed out in the comment that would be safe even with regular `std::vector` or, let me add, with simple arrays.

Comment: Thank you, guys.<br></br>I just wanted to check either I understand it right way.